# How to do dom manipulation in express js?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I am using express js for my web application. I am using 'ejs' files to render my views. I am also using 'ejs layout' to include other 'ejs' files in the layout files.
I have a login form which is get opened as a modal when i click on the **login** link given on the page.
when i submit the form I have checked whether the user is exists or not in the database. Depending upon the response I want to show **login successfully** or 'invalid username or password' message on the same modal page. for that purpose i have taken a div on the modal which is initially `display:none`.

The problem I am facing is that when I use `res.redirect('back')` it get redirected to the previous page on which modal popup is `display : none`. I am trying to make it 'display:block' using dom manipulation but it doesn't work.

Please help me out

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var user_name = req.body.inputEmail;
    var pwd = req.body.inputPassword;

    db.collection('userInfo').findOne({
        "username": user_name
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (user != null) {
            if (user.username == user_name && user.password == pwd) {
                request('http://localhost:3000/', function(error, response, body) {
                    console.log("*-----body     =", body);
                    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    res.redirect('back', function() {
                        $('#myModal').css({
                            'display': 'block',
                            'opacity': '1'
                        });
                        $('#msg').text("login successfully....");
                        $('#msg').css('display', 'block');
                    });
                });
            } else {
                res.send("invalid username or password..");
            }
        } else {
            res.send("invalid username or password..");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why you need access to another server to get the html error.
The best is a template variable.

Comment: You can't. Express is server side

Comment: @Tushar: I have this code in 'routes' directory which contains routing js files...so you mean i can't do dom manipulation there?

Comment: @pritamkale Yes, you don't have DOM available on server side

Comment: @RAUL :  i am not trying to get any html error.. i just want to show a message on the modal popup

Comment: The question is why you did a request (equest('http://localhost:3000/') to get the html error.

Comment: @Tushar: But i have put console.log("*-----body     =", body); which prints all html document in which i have all the elements...also when in firebug i run $('#myModal').css({'display':'block','opacity':'1'}); i get object with length=1

Comment: @RAUL: that is the url of the page whose html I want. So that i could find the  'div' element to show my message

Comment: And this page is in the same server? Or is another different server.

Comment: @RAUL: it is the starting point of the app. it loads the 'layout.ejs' file from the view directory on which i have included 'header.ejs' page which has link 'login' to open the modal popup login form. so answer to your question is all pages are on same server.

Comment: In this case, forget do a request('http://localhost:3000/' ...
Load directly the ejs and add pass a variable to your template and change this value in function of this variable.